# How to create a list from a dropdown depending on the list with x values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, in the image below, I have a dropdown from a-j, and I want to return a list, if I selected "a" from the drop down, the list will return (q,w,r,t,y)

[image]

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!$C$2:$X$2,Sheet1!$C$4:$X$26="x","")
```

Comment: As you applied the tag "Excel 2010": This version of Excel doesn't support the `FILTER`-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(B1:G1,FILTER(B2:G11,A2:A11=J1)="x")
```

[image]